# Creating test groups with grunt-mocha-test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, gruntjs, mocha.js

I'm using `grunt-mocha-test` to run node server side tests.
My Gruntfile.js looks like this

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Add the grunt-mocha-test tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');

  grunt.initConfig({
    // Configure a mochaTest task
    mochaTest: {
      test: {
        options: {
          reporter: 'dot'
        },
        src: [ 'test/setup.js', 'test/*.test.js' ]
      }
    },

  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', 'mochaTest');
};
```

What I want to do is this, I want to be able to run different test groups with different commands as follows

`grunt` will run all tests

`grunt test1` runs a subset of tests in the test folder, and

`grunt test2` runs another subset of tests

I don't know if this is possible, and I haven't been able to find anything about this in the  documentation for `grunt-mocha-test`

I could sure use some help here.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment you have one group called `test`. Just add another object inside `mochaTest` and call `grunt mochaTest:test2`.

Comment: +1 thanks. Agreed, the github readme for grunt-mocha-test missed this useful how-to.